# How to make ng-if to interrupt css transition

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions

I have 2 buttons which substitute each other regarding to its ng-if context. (like button A will show if **VAR** is **true**, and button B otherwise)

My problem is, since these buttons have been applied with css-transitions (actually only their background-color properties)

When I changed **VAR** from **true** to **false**, the button did not disappear suddenly.

And when I removed the css-transitions, the problem disappeared.

I would like to keep the css-transitions.

Anyone can suggest me a way to solve this ?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I just tried it on jsfiddle and it worked fluently, no problem at all. I now think that the problem is something else .. and for now I shall close this post. (even though I don't know how to)

Comment: maybe uses of ng-class can help u